# Return an Error if not true (python)

Tags: python, regex, command-line, formatting

I have a list of rules for a given input file for my function. If any of them are violated in the file given, I want my program to return an error message and quit.

- the first line should start with a '#' symbol (indicating a header line)
- every line should have exactly 10 columns
- column 2 (counting from 0) should be either a + or - symbol
- column 8 should be a comma-separated list of integers
- column 9 should be a comma-separated list of integers, with exactly the same number of integers as column 8.

To attempt to do this I have written the following code:

**Edited steveha's answer into code**

```
with open(infile, 'r') as fp:
line = fp.readline().strip()
if not line.startswith('#'):
    print ('First line does not start with #')
    sys.exit(1)
n = 1
for line in fp.readlines():
    d = '(\d+,\d+)'
    n += 1
    cols = line.strip().split()
    i = search(d, line)
    if len(cols) != 10:
        print('Lenth not equal to 10')
        sys.exit(1)
    if cols[2] != '+' or '-':
        print('Column 2 is not a + or - symbol')
        sys.exit(1)
    if i and cols[8] != i.group(1):
        print('Column 8 is not a comma-separated list of integers')
        sys.exit(1)
    if i and cols[9] != i.group(1) and len(cols[9]) != len(cols[8]):
        print('Column 9 in not a comma-separated list of integers with the exact same number of integers in column 8')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Yet, when I run this, not all the conditionals appear to be functional. I am trying to do this correctly?

Comment: Which conditions aren't working? (Note that your regex will only check for two integers, not any number of integers.) Also, you can't rely on the length of columns if you want the same number of integers. e.g. `3,4` and `30000,40000` contain the same number of integers, but are different lengths. (Also, `30000,40000` and `3,4,5,6,7,8` are the same length, but with different numbers of integers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
if cols[2] != '+' or '-':
```

This would be correct:

```
if not (cols[2] == '+' or cols[2] =='-'):
```

I would suggest this instead:

```
if cols[2] not in ('+', '-'):
```

Also, I suggest you not call `fp.readlines()`.  The file object `fp` works as an iterator, and when you iterate it you get one line at a time.  So your loop would then become:

```
for line in fp:
```

Also, it looks like `n` is keeping track of line number?  In that case, there is an idiomatic Python way you can do it, like so:

```
for n, line in enumerate(fp, 1):
```

`enumerate()` takes an iterator and returns the next value from the iterator together with an incrementing count.  By default the count starts at 0, but you can optionally specify a starting number, as I did here to make it start at 1.

And it is best practice in Python to use the `with` statement to open files, so I suggest you do this:

```
with open(infile, 'r') as fp:
    line = fp.readline().strip()
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        print ('First line does not start with #')
        sys.exit(1)
    for line in fp:
        # process lines here
```

The code you are showing does not fully make sense to me.  This line:

```
i = search(d, line)
```

You must have already done a `from re import search` command.  I actually recommend just doing `import re` and then explicitly calling `re.search()` but I guess that is a matter of preference.  Anyway, this sets `i` to the match group result from `re.search()` (or to `None` if the match fails).  But later on in the code you are testing `r` rather than `i`, and you never set `r` in any code we see here so I am not sure what that will do.  Personally I use `m` as the variable name for a match group.

Your regular expression just matches a pair of positive integers.  Nothing there counts how many integers there are.  `len(cols[8])` is checking how many characters in `cols[8]`.

You are calling a string method function `.split('')`, which is not correct.  On my system it raises an exception: `ValueError: empty separator`  Just call `.split()` to split on white space; I'll assume that the comma-separated integers lists must not have any white space.

Finally, please consider the guidelines in PEP 8.  Your variable `FirstLine` is capitalized like a class name rather than a variable name; that didn't exactly confuse me, but it was sort of distracting.  Most of the Python community follows PEP 8.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Taking all of the above into account, I simply re-wrote your code:

```
import sys

def parse_list_of_int(s):
    try:
        return [int(x) for x in s.split(',')]
    except Exception:
        return None

with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    # read line 1
    line = f.readline().strip()
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        print ('First line does not start with #')
        sys.exit(1)

    # need to start enumerate() at 2 because we pulled line 1 out above
    for i, line in enumerate(f, 2):
        cols = line.strip().split()
        if len(cols) != 10:
            print('line {0}: Length not equal to 10'.format(i))
            sys.exit(1)
        if cols[2] not in ('+', '-'):
            print('line {0}: Column 2 is not a + or - symbol'.format(i))
            sys.exit(1)
        lst8 = parse_list_of_int(cols[8])
        if lst8 is None:
            print('line {0}: Column 8 is not a comma-separated list of integers').format(i)
            sys.exit(1)
        lst9 = parse_list_of_int(cols[9])
        if lst9 is None:
            print('line {0}: Column 9 is not a comma-separated list of integers'.format(i))
            sys.exit(1)
        if len(lst8) != len(lst9):
            print('line {0}: Column 8 and column 9 do not have same number of integers'.format(i))
            sys.exit(1)

print('No problems!')
sys.exit(0)
```

I wrote a simple function to parse out the list of integers, build a Python list, and return it.  Then the code can actually check properly whether the two lists are the same length.

Comment: Thanks, does the rest appear to be correct. Especially this part:
column 8 should be a comma-separated list of integers
column 9 should be a comma-separated list of integers, with exactly the same number of integers as column 8.

Comment: So, after the first line conditional, I would write it as 'for n, line in enumerate(fp, 1) or still as for line in fp?

Comment: You're right, I did from re import *. Then since the variable was i, the later should be changed from r.search to i.search. I have also changed the split method, as you have described

Comment: I am new to some of this, could you help me understand why each print statement includes a .format(i) at the end. Additionally, could you put into words what the parse_list_of_int is doing?

Comment: The `.format()` is to put the line number into the error message.  I changed the line number from `n` to `i`; sorry if that confused you, but I'm just more used to using `i` for counters.  Here is a nice explanation of the `.format()` method: http://www.openbookproject.net/books/bpp4awd/ch06.html

Comment: Oh, I believe I understand now. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: `parse_list_of_int()` takes a string and parses it as a list of comma-separated integer values.  It returns a Python list of `int` values.  It takes the string values produced by `.split(',')` and coerces them to `int` values.  Because it is a list comprehension, it returns a list of values.  If any error occurs (most likely because the string was not a valid list of integers) an exception would be raised; the `try` block catches the exception and returns a `None` value instead.  Learn about list comprehsnions: http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/learning-python-by-example-list-comprehensions/